# Jquery Addition and Percentage calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate percentage and addition using JQuery. Addition can properly run but percentage calculation cannot. My code is below. 
How can I change it and calculate the percentage?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
 <head> 
 <title></title> 

 </head> 
 <body> 
 <br/><br /> 

 <form id="jquery_percentage"> 
 <label>Total Marks</label> 
 <input type="text" name="total_marks" id="total_marks"/> 
 <br/> 
 <br/> 
 <label>Written Marks</label> 
 <input type="text" name="written_marks" id="written_marks"/> 
 <br/> 
 <br/> 
 <label>Viva Marks</label> 
 <input type="text" name="viva_marks" id="viva_marks"/> 
 <br/> 
 <br/> 
 <label>Grooming Marks</label> 
 <input type="text" name="grom_marks" id="grom_marks"/> 
 <br/> 
 <br/> 
 <label>Obtain Marks</label> 
 <input type="text" name="obt_marks" id="obt_marks"/> 
 <br/> 
 <br/> 
 <label>Percentage Marks</label> 
 <input type="text" name="perc_marks" id="perc_marks"/> 
 <br/> 
 <br/> 
 <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 
 </form> 
 <div id="return"></div> 
  </body> 
 </html> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script>

$('#written_marks, #grom_marks, #viva_marks').change(function(){
    var written_marks = parseFloat($('#written_marks').val()) || 0;
    var grom_marks = parseFloat($('#grom_marks').val()) || 0;
    var viva_marks = parseFloat($('#viva_marks').val()) || 0;

    $('#obt_marks').val(written_marks + viva_marks + grom_marks);    
});
</script>
<script>

$('#total_marks, #obt_marks').change(function(){
    var total_marks = parseFloat($('#total_marks').val());
    var obt_marks = parseFloat($('#grom_marks').val());
    //var viva_marks = parseFloat($('#viva_marks').val()) || 0;

    $('#perc_marks').val((obt_marks * 100) / total_marks);    
});
</script>
```

Comment: What will happen if the user enters `0` in `#total_marks` input?

Comment: Total marks always 100, I will do it mandatory field later

Comment: Please also note that you didn't bind the second event to `#grom_marks` (Only to `#total_marks, #obt_marks`)

Comment: How to calculate percentage?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nature of the problem, it seem that this line: `$('#total_marks, #obt_marks').change(function(){` should be `$('#total_marks, #grom_marks').change(function(){` because at the moment the event doesn't fires if you change `#grom_marks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You onChange event occurs when you actually go to the element and change its value. It doesn't trigger automatically if you are just changing it's value dynamically. In this case you have to trigger the event like this `$("#obt_marks").trigger("change");`. Check the snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <br/><br />

  <form id="jquery_percentage">
    <label>Total Marks</label>
    <input type="text" name="total_marks" id="total_marks" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Written Marks</label>
    <input type="text" name="written_marks" id="written_marks" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Viva Marks</label>
    <input type="text" name="viva_marks" id="viva_marks" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Grooming Marks</label>
    <input type="text" name="grom_marks" id="grom_marks" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Obtain Marks</label>
    <input type="text" name="obt_marks" id="obt_marks" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Percentage Marks</label>
    <input type="text" name="perc_marks" id="perc_marks" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <div id="return"></div>
</body>

</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#written_marks, #grom_marks, #viva_marks').change(function() {
    var written_marks = parseFloat($('#written_marks').val()) || 0;
    var grom_marks = parseFloat($('#grom_marks').val()) || 0;
    var viva_marks = parseFloat($('#viva_marks').val()) || 0;

    $('#obt_marks').val(written_marks + viva_marks + grom_marks);
    $("#obt_marks").trigger("change");
  });
</script>
<script>
  $('#total_marks, #obt_marks').change(function() {
    var total_marks = parseFloat($('#total_marks').val());
    var obt_marks = parseFloat($('#obt_marks').val());
    //var viva_marks = parseFloat($('#viva_marks').val()) || 0;

    $('#perc_marks').val((obt_marks * 100) / total_marks);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what did you enter it's showing right to me. You are just doing grom_marks/total remember. I haven't updated any code

Comment: and you would be getting percentage as 10 for this dataset according to your code. you want me to update it to get 60%??

Comment: total marks= 100 viva =10 written =40 grom =10 total marks=60 (Correct) but percentage =10 (Wrong). Percentage = 60% (Because full marks(here total marks) 100, obtain total marks=60 ). so percentage is 60%

Comment: @jony you are calculating percentage of grom to the total. Let me update your code for you bro.

Comment: @jony Glad I helped :)